# Centering inline elements with divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the h3 element in the footer of my homepage, while placing the div `sms-links`off to the left of this. However, the div is knocking the h3 off center when added. I'd be grateful for any tips.

```css
footer {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #fffff;
  display: inline-table;
}

.sms-links {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 12em;
  margin: 0.8em;
}

footer h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="sms-links">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
        <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
        <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
      </picture>
    </a>

    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
      <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
    </picture>

    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
      <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <h3>Copyright: Tokyo Neighbourhoods 2017</h3>
</footer>
```

Comment: just a point on semantics, headings should not be used for styling.  But are you wanting the the text to be centred relative to the remaining space or to the whole footer?

Comment: .sms-links : `position: absolute;`

Comment: Also I don't see how you can put the images off to the left of the h3 when your images may take up 1800px - that is much larger than most desktops

Comment: @Pete i see allot of wrong but answered it just based on the question.

Comment: @Ylama it's unclear what the OP wants so I have asked for clarification and voted to close and moved on, if they update their question and it reappears in the questions when am on I may take another look

Comment: @Pete hahaha alright.

Comment: @moneytrick check my answer should help, if not let me know

Comment: @pete Many thanks for your help.

The position: absolute worked a charm. As you may be able to tell, I'm new to this whole thing.

Comment: @Ylama Many thanks for your help.

The position: absolute worked a charm. As you may be able to tell, I'm new to this whole thing.

Comment: @monkeytrick my pleasure just mark my awnser as accepted please , then its solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps, just change the position of `.sms-links`: to `absolute`

this helps, but you wil have to do some mobile @media queries as well.. for responsive.

```css
footer {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #fffff;
    display: inline-table;
}

.sms-links {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12em;
    margin: 0.8em;
}

footer h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="sms-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target=_blank">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                    <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                </picture> 
                </a>

                <picture>
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
                    <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                    <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                    <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                </picture> 
             </div>
          <h3>Copyright: Tokyo Neighbourhoods 2017</h3>
      </footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: @monkeytrick sure bro, just upvote if you want to as well sure it gives you a point or 2 not just to me, happy coding :).

Answer (score 0):

I have change `.sms-links` to `position: absolute;` and `left: 1em;`

And Removed `width:100%` from `h3`

And your color code of `box-shadow` is not proper. It should be `box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #fff`;

Hope this helps :)

```css
footer {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #fff;
  display: inline-table;
}

.sms-links {
  float: left;
  position: absolute; /*Change this to absolute*/
  left: 1em;/*set left as per requirement*/
  margin: 0.8em;
}

footer h3 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  /*width: 100%;*//*Remove this*/
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="sms-links">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
      <picture>
        <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
        <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
        <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
      </picture>
    </a>

    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
      <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
    </picture>

    <picture>
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
      <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
      <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <h3>Copyright: Tokyo Neighbourhoods 2017</h3>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This hope this will work

```
            <style>
                  footer {
                     height: auto;
                     width: 100%;
                     background-color: #1c1c1c;
                     margin-top: 1.2em;
                     box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 10px #fffff;
                     display: inline-table;
                  }

             .sms-links {
                 float: left;
                 position: inherit;
                  left: 12em;
                 margin: 0.8em;
             }

             footer h3 {
                 font-size: 17px;
                 font-weight: 200;
                 color: white;
                  width: 100%;
                 text-align: center;
                  margin: 0.8em;
               }
        </style>
       <footer>
            <p class="sms-links"
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target=_blank">
                 <picture>
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
            </picture> 
            </a>

            <picture>
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
                <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/pics/facebook_med.png">
            </picture>

            <picture>
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/" media="(max-width: 900px)">
                <source srcset="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
                <img src="http://tokyoneighbourhoods.com/">
            </picture> 
         </p>
         <h3>Copyright: Tokyo Neighbourhoods 2017</h3>
       </footer>
```

Answer (score -2):

A div by default is a block element. So use the display property to make it an inline element. Secondly, as H3 is a text element, center it using CSS. If you want to center the text inline with the logos, add a line-height property to the H3 and adjust it.

```
.sms-links {display:inline;}
footer h3 {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: the div has been floated and the h3 already has text-align center on it in the OPs code.  Also h3 is a block element, not a text element so this is wrong on all sorts of levels